# Issues with ModelState.IsValid always is true and gives error when insert on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

Issues with ModelState.IsValid always is true and gives error when insert on submit

Her is my ViewModel (CompaniesViewModel.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace kambi4.Models
{
    public class CompaniesViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Company Name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Company Name: ")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Company Legal ID is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Company Legal ID: ")]
        public string LegalId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Contact Email is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Please insert a valid Email")]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Email: ")]
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Contact Name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Name: ")]
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Contact Phone is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Phone: ")]
        public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the Controller (or functions of controller where i have the issue) (CompanyController.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace kambi4.Controllers
{
    public class CompanyController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Company/
        Models.EADBDataContext dc = new Models.EADBDataContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RegisterCompany()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterCompany(Models.CompaniesViewModel company)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //<- Is always true here
            {
                var a = new Models.companies();

                a.company = company.Company;
                a.companycode = (new Guid()).ToString();
                a.email = company.ContactEmail;
                a.contactname = company.ContactName;
                a.contactphone = company.ContactPhone;
                a.legalid = company.LegalId;
                a.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now;
                a.status = 3;

                dc.companies.InsertOnSubmit(a);
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Save Failed. Check the fields for errors");
            }
            return View(company);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RegisterClient()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterClient(Models.ClientModel Client)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Save Failed. Check the fields for errors");
            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

And last but not least important my View (RegisterCompany.cshtml)

```
@model kambi4.Models.CompaniesViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register as Service Company";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Create Company Failed. Check your fields");                                                                         
    <div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Register as Service Company</legend>
    <table id="RegisterCompany">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Company)</td>
        <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Company, new { @class = "k-input" })</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Company)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.LegalId)</td>
        <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.LegalId, new { @class = "k-input" })</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.LegalId)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.ContactName)</td>
        <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.ContactName, new { @class = "k-input" })</td>
        <td><span class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.ContactName)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.ContactPhone)</td>
        <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.ContactPhone, new { @class = "k-input" })</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.ContactPhone)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.ContactEmail)</td>
        <td align="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.ContactEmail, new { @class = "k-input" })</td>
        <td align="left"><span class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.ContactEmail)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Create" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, is always entering to save the model, obviously is giving me a null reference error, when i submit with a blank form.

Comment: Consider posting back a `Company` rather than a `CompanyViewModel`.  The purpose of a view model is fairly embedded in its name.  The validation error you're seeing is because you're attempting to save a `Company` that's invalid (even though your `CompanyViewModel` is valid).

Comment: @48klocs what ? Post back a company from a view's form having a companyViewModel as model ????

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem that you're having is that MVC is auto-validating a `CompanyViewModel` (and the data that you're posting back there constitutes a valid `CompanyViewModel`), then manually mapping that to a `Company`, which is not valid (and I can't speak to the reason(s) why as you didn't provide that class definition).

You can manually call validation on the `Company` object that you construct in your postback or you can have MVC bind your posted values to a `Company` instead, which will lead it to performing auto-validation like you expect.

If you go that route, you'll also need to write a method to transform a `Company` object to a `CompanyViewModel` object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterCompany(company.Company company)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            company.companycode = (new Guid()).ToString();
            company.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now;
            company.status = 3;

            dc.companies.InsertOnSubmit(company);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Save Failed. Check the fields for errors");
        }

        var companyViewModel = GetViewModel(company);  //transform left as an exercise to the author
        return View(companyViewModel );
    }
```